# First process that is killed on shutdown command

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

What is that first process that is executed when system shutdown command is executed. I want to run a custom script before any command that is killing all my process. The scenario is, I am using a EC2 instance on AWS and on clicking terminate instance, so I want to perform some actions before any of my process is killed.

Comment: `shutdown` just tells `init` (or whatever first process was started) to terminate. What `init` does then depends on the particular implementation, i.e. systemd or SysV-init or whatever else you might find out there. In any case, there are hooks you can install to trigger actions during shutdown and that's probably the way to go. I say "probably", because you seem to be having a so-called "XY problem" (do some research what that means!).

Comment: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/342638)